# Automatically kill Linux process / php script after given time

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am running a crawler programed in PHP every hour with a cron job. When everythings goes as expected, the script quits automatically. However, for some reasons, sometimes it gets stuck in an infinite loop. It gets worse because I use a lock file to avoid a duplicate run, when the crawler gets stuck it never runs again until it kill it manually ( ps aux -> kill )

How can I make sure that the script ends after a couple of hours whatever happens?

Should I add a line in the php code? Wouldn't it be more robust to do that directly in Linux?

The best idea that I have so far is to make a small batch file with all the necessary commands and then invoke that batch with cron instead of the php script directly.

Am I right, and what should the commands be?

Thanks

Edit: the best I found so far is: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-kill-the-process-after-specific-time-624453

The bash is way too long, I was hoping for a smarter, shorter solution.

Cheers

Comment: I would add some logging code to figure out the infinite loop issue instead. It will probably be better in the long run.

Comment: Obviously this is the best solution. Nonetheless, given that I am crawling many websites and that they change all the time, I need to find a solution to my question..

Comment: you could add a timer so that you spent a maximum of x seconds per website. I would do this by spawning a new thread for every website, and then killing it when the timer elapses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would kill php process which were started more then an hour ago:

```
$(ps -eo comm,pid,etimes | awk '/^php/ {if ($3 > 3600) { print "kill "$2}}')
```

3600 - timestamp in second

P.S. You can run command

```
> ps -eo comm,pid,etimes
```

before and after to ensure that everything worked out.

P.P.S. I know it is old question but someone might find it helpful